# Hiding a button control when submitting Infopath form to Sharepoint Form Library

Tags: infopath, form, libraries

I'm creating a public facing form that needs to have the standard Submit button at the bottom of the form.  The forms are stored in a Sharepoint form library for staff to review.  The problem I'm running into is when one of the forms is opened in the library it still contains the custom button at the bottom of the page.  This is potentially confusing to staff and I'd to store the form as is *without* the button.

I've tried a hidden boolean field that switches upon clicking the button and then using conditional format to hide the button based on the value of that field.  The problem is conditional formatting rules always comes before Action rules.
[image: format always comes before action]

I then tried switching to a view that replicates the form (minus the submit button) and submitting to the data connection based on the value of that hidden field.  For some reason, that view is not what is sent to the form library.

Is there a way to get it to send the new view somehow rather than the original?  Or is there a better way to hide this either in Infopath of on the Sharepoint side?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the logic to set the boolean field just before the submit rule on the button, and have the formatting rule on the button to hide it when that boolean field == true.

If you add this logic to the field after the submitting rule, it will not be saved with the form, and next time users open the form it won't be hidden as the rule to hide it came after the submit.

Comment: Thank you.  The boolean field logic actually is before the data submission.  The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a way to put the conditional formatting after the switch.    That was my thinking as well.  Apparently Infopath always puts the formatting first.  I've spent all day trying to come up with a work-around.  BTW, I forgot to mention I'm on 2013 for both Sharepoint and Infopath.

Comment: Where are you doing the validation?

Comment: Also why not just add the action to set the "DoNotShowSubbmit" after you switch to the second view? I am not sure if am following you right here.. The sequence is to validate the data.. if everything is ok then set the field to true then submit and switch view. What are you doing exactly?

Comment: For right now I am not doing any validation.

Comment: OK, so can you clarify based on the steps I mentioned in my previous comment, how is it not working with these steps?

Comment: I can see how that screen shot can be confusing.  I just added in that conditional formatting to post here so as to illustrate the behavior (or my inability to move that below/after the boolean switch.

Comment: The DoNotShowSubmit control is the hidden boolean field.  The "Switch to eliminate submit button view" action was my latest attempt to do much like you said. (and at that point I disabled the "hide submit button" conditional formatting and the Submit and "Switch to Thank you" actions in the view from above).  In the view without the button - I then added an action to submit to the data connection if the DoNotShowSubmit field = True.  This worked but still showed the button in the document library in sharepoint.

Comment: Can you try on the same page, without switching or anything, to change the value of the DoNotShowSubmit and see if the button will be hidden/disabled?

Comment: I can change the value of DoNotShowSubmit on the "Main" view as you suggest, but as I mentioned before, the conditional formatting (what would hide the button control) is, for some reason, required (by Infopath, not my logic) to run before that particular action - which stinks because  it is backwards for my purposes.

Comment: Hello @mclatch I facing the same issue, where you able to find a work around on this. Can you please share, it ll be very useful.